# AES Decrypt in .NET Framework fails

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, aes

I am trying to send a username through an HTTP header to my service, and I want it encrypted with AES. (Yes, this could be done in a better way)

The final decrypted string is always empty.

Encript:

```
using var aes = Aes.Create();
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
aes.GenerateIV();
aes.Key = SHA256.HashData(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(PK));
var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
using StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream, Encoding.Unicode);
string payload = UserProvider.User;

streamWriter.Write(payload);
cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
string encryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(array);
string ivString = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.IV);

_client.AddDefaultHeader("user", encryptedString);
_client.AddDefaultHeader("iv", ivString);
```

Decrypt:

```
internal static class Authentication
{
    private const string PK = "MySecretKey";
    public static string DecryptUser(string encrypted, string iv)
    {

        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] pkBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(PK);
            byte[] pkHash = sha.ComputeHash(pkBytes);
            byte[] ivBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(iv);
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            aes.Key = pkHash;
            aes.IV = ivBytes;
            var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

            byte[] cipher = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipher))
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
            {
                string user = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                if (user.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) throw new Exception("Authentication failed.");

                return user;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Things I already checked:

- The CipherMode is correct
- The PaddingMode is correct
- The Base64 strings I receive are not empty or corrupted
- I tried seeking to 0 on the MemoryStream
- I tried sending longer content to see if the problem is the minimum block size in the decryptor
- I tried copying the CrytoStream into another MemoryStream but the resulting buffer is empty
- Stepping over `ReadToEnd()` makes the `cryptoStream.HasFlushedFinalBlock` go from false to true

I am running .NET Framework 4.8 on the server (decrypt side), and .NET 8 on the client (encrypt side).

EDIT: I wrote a small xUnit test completely excluding the Base64/HTTP part, and it still does not work.

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
        {
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            aes.Key = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Password"));

            using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream, Encoding.Unicode))
            {
                string payload = "username";

                streamWriter.Write(payload);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
                Assert.NotEmpty(buffer);
            }
            using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream, Encoding.Unicode))
            {
                string user = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                Assert.True(streamReader.EndOfStream);
                Assert.True(cryptoStream.HasFlushedFinalBlock);
                Assert.Equal("username", user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When doing anything with encryption it is a good idea to have a unit test that tries to round-trip some data. It is probably also a good idea to start with the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-8.0), and do gradual changes. That way you should know whenever you mess something up.

Comment: Actually, without the encryption code, this question can only be answered by guessing. So post the encryption code.

Comment: One (of several possibilities) is the encoding. In the decryption code, `Unicode` is used to encode the password (`PK`). `Unicode` in .NET specifies UTF-16LE. Maybe during encryption the more common UTF-8 was applied. However, to check this (or other possible causes), the encryption code is required.

Comment: You are not getting any exceptions.  So everything is working.  The issue is that you are are the end of the stream and need to set the position to zero before reading.  So you are reading at the end of the stream and getting an empty string.

Comment: @jdweng As stated, I already tried seeking to position 0 on the MemoryStream but it does not work. CrytoStream does not support seeking.

Comment: What about the StreamReader?

Comment: @jdweng StreamReader does not support seeking either.

Comment: Both codes use different modes of operation (ECB vs CBC).

Comment: @Topaco Thanks, I copied the two segments in different moments while testing. The CipherModes are aligned in the real code

Comment: The **en**cryption code seems buggy (not only because of the inconsistent mode). Post non-productive test data: Plaintext, test key, Base64 encoded IV and ciphertext.

Comment: Just noticed that you have changed the mode from CBC to ECB. That makes no sense. ECB does not use an IV! Also, ECB is insecure.

Comment: @Topaco Sorry, I don't really know what these algorithms do. I'll make sure to use CBC then.

Comment: On my machine the encryption does not work. To check whether this problem plays a role for you, share concrete test data.

Comment: @Topaco My real data is just an AD username with domain attached. Something like "DOMAIN\\USERNAME". The encryption just follows the Microsoft example plus the `FlushFinalBlock` because my payload is shorter than 16 bytes sometimes.

Comment: Your encryption does not work. Remove `cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()` and use `streamWriter.Close()` instead. Try this. It would all be much easier if you posted concrete test data.

Comment: @Topaco That actually fixes it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the call to `cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()` is not sufficient to ensure that the payload was actually encrypted.

I had to add a call to `streamWriter.Flush()` **before** it to actually pass the bytes from the StreamWriter's internal buffer to his inner Stream.

Alternatively, I could have called `streamWriter.Close()`.

```cs
// Works
streamWriter.Write(payload);
streamWriter.Flush();
cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

// Works
streamWriter.Write(payload);
streamWriter.Close();

// Does not work!
streamWriter.Write(payload);
cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

// Does not work!
streamWriter.Write(payload);
streamWriter.Flush();
cryptoStream.Flush();
```